# Meaning of "I've scoured your mail"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of the sentence 'I've scoured your mail'? I know what scouring and mail mean but I can't find a correlation.

Some context: it's from a comics set in the middle ages. The complete line is:

> I've scoured your mail and polished your greaves, gorget and breastplate, ser.

Thank you

Comment: If someone told me they'd scoured my mail, I'd report them to my sysadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scour](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Ascour&oq=define%3Ascour) means to clean or brighten a surface by rubbing it. And mail was a type of [medieval armour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_(armour)). So it just means that they cleaned the person's armour.

Answer (score 2):

All the other [direct objects](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/direct-object) in that sentence are pieces of armor: [greaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greave), [gorget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorget#As_part_of_armour), [breastplate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breastplate). So if you know what [scouring](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scour) means you will understand that there is a very high probability, in the context of the sentence, that "mail" refers to [chain mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_(armour)) and not [letters](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mail).